# NSString to NSArray and editing every object

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsarray

I have an `NSString` filled with objects seperated by a comma

```
NSString *string = @"1,2,3,4";
```

I need to seperate those numbers and store then into an array while editing them, the result should be

```
element 0 = 0:1,
element 1 = 1:2,
element 2 = 2:3,
element 3 = 3:4.
```

How can i add those to my objects in the string ??

Thanks.

**P.S : EDIT**

I already did that :

```
NSString *string = @"1,2,3,4";
NSArray *array = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

[array objectAtIndex:0];//1
[array objectAtIndex:1];//2
[array objectAtIndex:2];//3
[array objectAtIndex:3];//4
```

I need the result to be :

```
[array objectAtIndex:0];//0:1
[array objectAtIndex:1];//1:2
[array objectAtIndex:2];//2:3
[array objectAtIndex:3];//3:4
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do with this, but can you show us what you have tried to get that desired result?

Comment: see the edit please @FahimParkar

Comment: ok... Why you want result like that? tell me what you exactly trying to do... you can do this in simple for loop also...

Comment: in for loop you can have `NSLog(@"%d:%d", i, (i+1));`

Comment: i need the array to be filled like that

Comment: check my answer.. hope this is what you wanted...

Comment: i just did .. thanks that works like the others !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In lieu of a built in `map` function (yey for Swift) you would have to iterate over the `array` and construct a new array containing the desired strings:

```
NSString *string = @"1,2,3,4";
NSArray *array = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

NSMutableArray *newArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:array.count];

[array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    [newArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu:%@", (unsigned long)idx, obj]];
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to do is separate the string into an array of component parts - NSString has a handy method for that : '-componentsSeparatedByString'.  Code should be something like this :

```
NSArray *components = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

So that gives you 4 NSString objects in your array.  You could then iterate through them to make compound objects in your array, though you arent exactly clear how or why you need those.  Maybe something like this :

```
NSMutableArray *resultItems = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSString *item in components)
{
    NSString *newItem = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: ... create your new item", item];
    [resultItems addObject:newItem];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
NSString *string = @"1,2,3,4";
NSArray *myOldarray = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
NSMutableArray *myNewArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i=0;i<myOldarray.count;i++) {
    [myNewArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%d", [myOldarray objectAtIndex:i], ([[myOldarray objectAtIndex:i] intValue]+1)]];
}

// now you have myNewArray what you want.
```

This is with consideration that in array you want `number:number+1`